# Determine the number of ordered triples

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, puzzle, combinatorial-proofs

**The question:** 
Determine the amount of ordered triples of sets $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ such that:

1. $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 =\{1,2,3....,10\}$,
2. $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$.

**My approach:** 
Consider the following variables: $p_1,....,p_{10}$. 
I want to divide them over $A_1,...,A_3$ such that the intersection of the three sets is empty. Since the order of the $p_i$ does not matter in this state, we can divide them by order so we start with set $A_1$ put numbers in there (or not), for instance $p_1,p_2$ then we switch to $A_2$ for instance $p_3,p_4,p_5$ and then we put the rest in $A_3$. 
We can see this type of division of the $p_i$ over the $A_{i}$ as a chain of 12 events where 2 of them are the event 'switch', so ${12 \choose 2}$ possibilities. 
Now we have to assign to $p_i$ to a number. We can say that $p_{1}$ has 10 options, $p_{2}$ 9 etc. That brings us to ${12 \choose 2} \times 10!$ 
Lastly we have to see how many options there are to order $A_{1},..,A_{3}$. This is $3!$. 
So the final answer would be:
$${12 \choose 2} \times 10! \times 3!$$

Is my approach correct? Thanks in advance
This question is not a duplicate since the other question doesn't mention an approach/check my proof.

Comment: Does 2. mean a) $A_1 \cap (A_2 \cap A_3)=\emptyset$ or b) $A_i \cap A_j=\emptyset$ when $i\ne j$?

Comment: Constraint 2 means b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting ordered triples of sets, with empty intersection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362604/counting-ordered-triples-of-sets-with-empty-intersection)

Comment: It does not answer my question as it does not give any explanation about the approach/doesnt check my approach

Comment: You're overcounting. for partition $(\emptyset,\emptyset,\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\})$ you're counting this triple exactly $10!$ times. The correct answer, based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/362614) approach, will yeild $3^{10}$ as you're simply to decide for each number into which of these $3$ sets it goes to.